# What is the type of decltype(*int_iterator + 0)?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename AIterator>
auto foo(AIterator begin) -> decltype(*begin + 0){
    return *begin;
}
```

For example:

```
vector<int> ivec = {1,2,3};
foo(ivec.begin());
```

**My answer book says it's  a `const reference` type, is it true?**

But IIRC, decltype(`int reference + int`), expression type is a `int` (`*begin` is a reference, so naturally I think `*begin + 0` should also result in a `int`).

For example:

```
int a = 3, &b = a;
decltype(b + 0) d; //d is a int
```

---

PS: I tried on VS and the IDE hints the return type of function `foo` is `int`.

The book is *C++ Primer 5th* answer book, but mine is not a English version and it's adapted by the translators, so I didn't mention it at first.

[image]

Comment: I think you are being fooled by some re-used terminology. `begin` is not a reference in the C++ syntax sense. It is an iterator. An iterator is or contains a reference (as in it refers to, tells you how to find) to an element in a container.

Comment: @user4581301: but type of `*it` is a *"reference"* (or wrapper value as for `std::vector<bool>`).

Comment: @user4581301 I know `begin` is an iterator.. I said `*begin` is a reference.

Comment: You should probably provide book title.

Comment: Your book is wrong (or have a typo).

Comment: @Jarod42 It's the *C++ Primer 5th* answer book, but adapted by some local experts.

Comment: @Jarod42 So the result type is `int` in your opinion? :D

Comment: Type is `int` as intellisense shows.

Comment: My apologies. I have mis-interpreted the question. You are wondering why the book states it should be `const`? I see no reason for the example given to result in `const int`.

Comment: @Jarod42  +_+, is this kind of hint really reliable? I mean, I've heard people saying that do not fully trust IDE hints.

Comment: @user4581301 no problem :D. I am wondering the why the book states it's `const reference`, the answer book is saying that it's a **reference**.

Comment: @Rick Though it's correct in this case, I'd say you're right not to 100% rely on such things!

Comment: Three different cuts at the example with small-but-important differences. Returns `int`: https://ideone.com/fGX8f0 Returns `int` reference: https://ideone.com/VilaTb . Returns `const` reference: https://ideone.com/3P8ASo

Comment: Personally, I'd tend to gravitate more towards `std::decay_t<decltype(*begin)>` or something along those lines...

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you very much for the 3 examples. Very helpful.

Comment: See effective modern c++, I think `decltype(b + 0) d` the type of `d` should actually be `int&` because that is different from `decltype(b) d`. (But maybe the compiler may optimize the `+0` out of here?).

Comment: @HanXIAO No, I am sure that it's a `int`, not a reference. If `decltype(b + 0) d`, `d` is a reference, then how could I only declare a reference without initialize?

Comment: @Rick Yeah you are right. I tried it again and `decltype((b)) d;`and `d` will be `int &` and cause compilation error.

Comment: @HanXIAO Ya my friend. One more thing you should know that `decltype((variable))` (with double parenthesis), always results in reference type. `decltype(variable)` results in a reference type when variable is reference. Or `decltype(*variable)`, deference a pointer you get a reference type. Quoted from *C++ Primer 5th*, Chapter 2.3.5.

Comment: @Rick Yeah, and I searched for additional materials here which explain it in a simplified way [C++ auto and decltype Explained][1]


  [1]: http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_01.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `int`, and this is exactly why the author has added `+ 0` … as a quick way to get rid of the reference type and ensure that `foo` returns a copy (which appears to be its purpose).

`decltype` on a *prvalue* expression of type `T` [always evaluates to `T`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Either the book's prose is wrong, or you've misread it.

Comment: Of course it really wouldn't hurt if `foo` had some documenting comment attached to it, explaining its purpose and how this `decltype`/`+0` trick accomplishes said purpose.

Comment: "*as a quick way to get rid of the reference type*" - seems like a lazy way to avoid using [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)

Comment: It's merely an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th*.  I've uploaded a screenshot, see https://imgur.com/wNy9CGc. I am sure it's the answer book's mistake. It's a translated version with some adaption by so-called expert translator, really unreliable sometimes. Btw, I like Daenerys too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the book mentions `remove_reference` at first.

Comment: Whenever I find myself thinking of `std::remove_reference_t` I'm in the habit of thinking "does `std::decay_t` fit better?  i.e. Do I also want to remove `const`?  If I pass a reference to function, do I want it to decay into a pointer to function?  If I pass a reference to array, do I want it to decay to a pointer to first element?"  IMO, in this case, the answers are all yes, so I would use `std::decay_t` instead of `std::remove_reference_t`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yep, it is

Comment: @Rick: Hah, good to see that there is indeed an explanatory comment!

Comment: BTW the answer is the iterator must support random access (or, more generally, `AIterator` must have an `op+`)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yeah me too I think, particularly as then the constraints on the iterator type would be removed

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why? The code is not invoking `operator+` on the iterator itself, but on the value that the iterator's `operator*` returns. Due to operator precedence, `*begin + 0` is treated as `(*begin) + 0`, not as `*(begin + 0)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Ah yes, derp